# Display data as user entered with space and line break while using htmlspeacialchars function

Tags: php, html

I am using 
`nl2br()`
function to add a line break and then
`htmlspeacialchars()`
but the code displays `<br/>` while it should have been a line break.
I have tried to put htmlspeacialchars() above but same output is displayed.
I'm fetching data from my database variable named blog while I'm displaying some code too viz "`<li>` or any other ".

```
$blog=htmlspecialchars($blog);
$blog=nl2br($blog);
```

and line break is echoed as:

```
<br />
```

And more over I don't want to use javascript.

Comment: removed sql tag there is no database component currently in your question

Comment: If you use `htmlspecialchars` _after_ `nl2br`, It would make sense that you would see `<br>` instead of a line break, but the order you have it in in the question shouldn't be doing that.

Comment: So can you please tell me how to fix that. As both of them are not working fine with each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found solution from [How to use add line break using nl2br while using htmlspeacialchars](http://havemybooks.com/blog_single?blog_no=38&blog=How%20to%20use%20add%20line%20break%20using%20nl2br%20while%20using%20htmlspeacialchars)
And they suggest using both functions in this way.As I was not able to realise what Don't panic suggested in his comment.

```
$text_even=nl2br(htmlspecialchars($text_uneven));
```